# Composer\Exception\NoSslException

Tags: php, laravel

When I am trying to create a laravel project using the command `laravel new projectname`, I am facing the following error:

> **Composer\Exception\NoSslException**
>
> The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.*

Later, I went inside the php.ini file and enable the OpenSSL extension

```
extension=openssl
```

But still, I am facing the same error.

Comment: Hi! can you check if you have correctly enabled the openssl extension through phpinfo?

Comment: thanks now, it is working fine, yes i didnt enabled it correctly